# Database Error "One or more database tables are unavailable" on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

Error:  `One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.`

How can i solve this problem?

wp-config.php is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use windows, xampp 7.1, and I get this wordpress database corruption every month. WP_ALLOW_REPAIR does nothing, wp repair just show everything ok. Nothing in debug log.

Anyways when went to phpmyadmin, I noticed wp_options table is unopenable and phpmyadmin adviced to repair it.

I repaired table using sql command -

```
repair table newdb28.wp_options use_frm;
```

use_frm is something that tells db to ignore index and recreate db by data only.

I could click and see data in wp_options but wordpress was still not working ..

I went to xampp to xampp7.1\mysql\bin\mysqlcheck in commandline (comandline runned as administrator) and run command to repair all tables in my database

```
mysqlcheck dbname -uroot --auto-repair --use-frm
```

That checked all tables to OK, but as you can guess wp still didnt worked.

Solution : I went to wp_options table , ordered by id, and noticed lowest id is 7. Then checked my other wp project and saw that rows here start with id 3, and that keys of 7+ are identical to my broken database .. so I exported those id 3-6 rows and imported them to other table and everything miraclously work ... (those missing lines in wp_options were nobrainer copy paste stuff, but first one was 'siteurl' which I set acordingly, if you have older or develop version of same project will easier it up).

Also checked my corupted db from month ago which I didnt delete for some reason, and it had same problem missing first 5 rows in wp_options table ...

Anyways if this help anyone in future was worth a fuss :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you have to add

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

above line in your wp-config.php file.

If this method will not work then you have to check if have a database backup then create a new database and a new user then import a backed-up database SQL file in the new database.
Then replace database credentials with the old ones in your wp-config.php file.

This method will help you.