# One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.(WORDRESS)

Tags: wordpress

Hello guys I've got 'One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.' this error after the import sql dump on my new created data base. But I think I am doin wrong thing I guess because it's stop working after I import my sql file. How can I fix it? I tried to repair my files with define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true) but it doesn't work for me.(Virtual ubuntu)

Comment: What are the export and import versions of WordPress ?

Comment: version is 5.9.2

Comment: Check this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182860/13378498. Its hard to tell where is your problem since we need to compare your tables and what is missing. Enable debug and check if there are some hints where the problem could be.

Comment: If the databases are on the same server try Phpmyadmin -> Operations -> Copy database to

Comment: I solved my issues. I oppened my dump with data grip and edit the wp_options file and it fixed :)